# jQuery library to format address & phone based on Country selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

Does anyone know of a jquery (or javascript) library that has all of the countries pre-coded to where you can select a country and it then creates a correct input mask for the address and telephone fields including auto generating the country code?

We have a job application where we get people from all over the world filling out apps. I dont want to custom make input masks for each country myself. Im hoping for something out of the box.

Thanks

Comment: You can use this JSON and build your own plugin, https://github.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes/blob/master/all/all.json. Seems fairly easy.

Comment: Thanks elclanrs. Post as reply and Ill vote for it.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what you mean by an "input mask"? How would you want that to work? I created this jquery plugin which adds a country dropdown to an input, and auto-populates the dial code etc: https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input if that solves part of your problem? Feel free to create an issue for any feature requests you have.

Comment: basically when someone chooses an international country, I want the address field to be formatted properly for that local as well as properly verify based on that local. for example some countries put zip codes first and contain a different character set than the US. Same with telephone numbers.